# Unable to start postgresql

Tags: linux, kali-linux, postgresql

Whenever trying to start `postgresql` however it fails. I am running Kali NetHunter.

Here's my terminal output

```
root@kali:~# service postgresql start
```

> ```
> [....] Starting PostgreSQL 10 database server: main[....] Error: /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/pg_ctl /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/pg_ctl start -D /var/lib/postgresql/10/main -l /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.log -s -o -c config_file="/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf" exited with status 1: 2018-02-07 09:29:59.653 UTC 0 LOG: listening on IPv6 address "::1", port 5432 2018-02-07 09:29:59.653 UTC 0 LOG: listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432 2018-02-07 09:29:59.654 UTC 0 LOG: listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" 2018-02-07 09:29:59.656 UTC 0 FATAL: could not create shared memory segment: Function not implemented 2018-02-07 09:29:59.656 UTC 0 DETAIL: Failed system call was shmget(key=5432001, size=40, 03600). 2018-02-07 09:29:59.656 UTC 0 LOG: database system is shut down pg_ctl: could not start [FAILr Examine the log output. ... failed!
>  failed!
> ```

And here's the log file

```
2018-02-06 16:31:36.775 UTC [6358] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::1", port 5432
2018-02-06 16:31:36.775 UTC [6358] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2018-02-06 16:31:36.783 UTC [6358] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2018-02-06 16:31:36.785 UTC [6358] FATAL:  could not create shared memory segment: Function not implemented
2018-02-06 16:31:36.785 UTC [6358] DETAIL:  Failed system call was shmget(key=5432001, size=40, 03600).
2018-02-06 16:31:36.785 UTC [6358] LOG:  database system is shut down
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
2018-02-06 16:57:52.984 UTC [8837] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::1", port 5432
2018-02-06 16:57:52.984 UTC [8837] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2018-02-06 16:57:52.985 UTC [8837] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2018-02-06 16:57:52.988 UTC [8837] FATAL:  could not create shared memory segment: Function not implemented
2018-02-06 16:57:52.988 UTC [8837] DETAIL:  Failed system call was shmget(key=5432001, size=40, 03600).
2018-02-06 16:57:52.988 UTC [8837] LOG:  database system is shut down
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
2018-02-06 16:57:53.693 UTC [8875] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::1", port 5432
2018-02-06 16:57:53.693 UTC [8875] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2018-02-06 16:57:53.694 UTC [8875] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2018-02-06 16:57:53.695 UTC [8875] FATAL:  could not create shared memory segment: Function not implemented
2018-02-06 16:57:53.695 UTC [8875] DETAIL:  Failed system call was shmget(key=5432001, size=40, 03600).
2018-02-06 16:57:53.696 UTC [8875] LOG:  database system is shut down
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
2018-02-07 02:57:25.787 UTC [15672] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::1", port 5432
2018-02-07 02:57:25.788 UTC [15672] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2018-02-07 02:57:25.788 UTC [15672] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2018-02-07 02:57:25.790 UTC [15672] FATAL:  could not create shared memory segment: Function not implemented
2018-02-07 02:57:25.790 UTC [15672] DETAIL:  Failed system call was shmget(key=5432001, size=40, 03600).
2018-02-07 02:57:25.791 UTC [15672] LOG:  database system is shut down
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
2018-02-07 03:13:39.986 UTC [17336] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::1", port 5432
2018-02-07 03:13:39.987 UTC [17336] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2018-02-07 03:13:39.988 UTC [17336] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2018-02-07 03:13:39.989 UTC [17336] FATAL:  could not create shared memory segment: Function not implemented
2018-02-07 03:13:39.989 UTC [17336] DETAIL:  Failed system call was shmget(key=5432001, size=40, 03600).
2018-02-07 03:13:39.989 UTC [17336] LOG:  database system is shut down
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
2018-02-07 06:26:52.218 UTC [32350] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::1", port 5432
2018-02-07 06:26:52.219 UTC [32350] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2018-02-07 06:26:52.219 UTC [32350] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2018-02-07 06:26:52.221 UTC [32350] FATAL:  could not create shared memory segment: Function not implemented
2018-02-07 06:26:52.221 UTC [32350] DETAIL:  Failed system call was shmget(key=5432001, size=40, 03600).
2018-02-07 06:26:52.222 UTC [32350] LOG:  database system is shut down
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
2018-02-07 09:29:59.653 UTC [10136] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::1", port 5432
2018-02-07 09:29:59.653 UTC [10136] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2018-02-07 09:29:59.654 UTC [10136] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2018-02-07 09:29:59.656 UTC [10136] FATAL:  could not create shared memory segment: Function not implemented
2018-02-07 09:29:59.656 UTC [10136] DETAIL:  Failed system call was shmget(key=5432001, size=40, 03600).
2018-02-07 09:29:59.656 UTC [10136] LOG:  database system is shut down
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`postgresql` is not up because it cannot create a big enough shared memory segment as seen by the error:

```
could not create shared memory segment: Function not implemented
Failed system call was shmget
```

To fix it, do:

```
sudo sysctl -w kernel.shmmax=134217728
```

For setting it permanently after reboots, edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` and append to it the `kernel.shmmax = 134217728`:

```
sudo vi /etc/sysctl.conf
kernel.shmmax = 134217728
```

UPDATE to the answer:

Debugging it with the OP help:

```
sudo sysctl -w kernel.shmmax=134217728 sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/kernel/shmmax: No such file or directory
```

That joined together that Kali NetHunter is for Android devices, the most correct and definitive answer is that `shmem`support was not compiled in this kernel version.

That also limits on not being able to run other software reliant on having `shmem` like `Apache`.

Alas, it also may not make much sense running a postgresql DB in an Android-class devices.

Nevertheless, a possible course of action is either trying to find another kernel package (if there is one), that support shmem, or at limit cross-compile a kernel. Obviously, you should not consider this route is your device is very low in disk and/or memory.

Comment: Actually I've tried it but it says
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/kernel/shmmax: No such file or directory

Comment: Here's the complete terminal output.       root@kali:~# sudo sysctl -w kernel.shmmax=134217728
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/kernel/shmmax: No such file or directory
root@kali:~#

Comment: @KrishnaDeshpandeKD Linux in Android. The kernel is probably compiled without support for shmem. No dice.